# Fastest Simplest way to use PNG textures in OpenGL

Tags: macos, opengl, png, textures

I am looking for the fastest and easiest way to use PNG (with alpha values) textures in OpenGL. I have tried many different libraries but most are bloated and hard to get compiled/working on a Mac.

I'm not very familiar with OpenGL textures and all of the "Gotchas" so I am putting emphasis on the Simple.

It would be very helpful if someone could give me a nice makefile example if the solution involves linking a library.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You might give [SOIL](http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html) a whirl.

Answer (score 1):

sdl and sdl_image is the simplest way I know of:
http://www.libsdl.org/
http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/

However, this is for cross-platform. For Mac-only I guess there is a native alternative.

Answer (score 1):

DevIL can do this pretty simply and easily, for quite a few formats. It also have a very, very similar API to OpenGL (by design, most constants are identical, etc). It took me just a few minutes to hook it into an OpenGL app I had. The docs aren't great, but it does the job and supports a lot of formats.

Comment: DevIL seems to be a nightmare to compile for OSX. :(

Answer (score 0):

[glpng](http://www.fifi.org/doc/libglpng-dev/glpng.html) is a png opengl loader utility library although one can do what it does with just libpng and gl it loads from a png file into a texture for you in one call

Comment: I could not figure out how to link glpng. When I tried to compile it for use on MacOSX I got several errors that I didn't know how to fix.